# merge items into one that are repeated in the same list

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query in the database that returns me a list of objects( in my case notifications), but that list brings a lot of repeated items(a notification can contain multiples attachments, so what the query does is a join with the attachment table, bringing back a lot of notificationid repeated, a notification with a lot of attachment). So what i want to acomplish is merge all the attachments for one specific notification id into one item (let say that my notification class has a list of attachments)
I did this:

```
Dim dupes = list.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Notification.NotifiedID)
                .Select(Function(s) s.ToList())
                .ToList()
```

but i don't know how to merge the grouped ones, any help here?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think you simply need to change `Select` to `SelectMany` to get what you want.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that will give me back the same input list, I want to merge the one that have the same id

Comment: You should have replied to @AustinSalonen

Answer (score 1):

Try this in c#

```
list.GroupBy(x=> x.Notification.NotifiedID).SelectMany(o=> o);
```

I don't know VB But you can try this

```
Dim dupes = list.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Notification.NotifiedID)
                .SelectMany(Function(s) s)
                .ToList()
```

Comment: that query returns me only the first one, very explicit, but I need all the grouped items by the same id and merge those items

Comment: yes that was the same suggestion that Austin Salonen gave me, but I need to merge the grouped items into only one

Answer (score 1):

After grouping, then select the first from each group:

```
var firstNotifiedItems = list.GroupBy(x=> x.Notification.NotifiedID).Select(g=> g.First()).ToList();
```

This will give you a single item for each notifiedID.

However, if you want all the items in a new object:

```
var notifiedItems = list.GroupBy(x=> x.Notification.NotifiedID).Select(g=> new{NotifiedID=g.First().NotifiedID, Items=g.ToList()}).ToList();
```

This will give you an object with the NotifiedID and a list of items for that ID.